# How do I do an eol-last check with ESLint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm writing a node project with syntax checking through ESLint. I want to meet POSIX standard and have a newline at the end of every file, so I set the `eol-last` test to `2` in my `.eslintrc`. However, this rule seems to be totally ignored while others work just fine.

I tried this `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "eol-last": 2,
    "no-console": 2
  }
}
```

and tested this file:

```
 console.log('Test');
```

In response, I get:

```
1:1  error  Unexpected console statement  no-console

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

It makes no sense to me. I've tried everything and the rule seems to be useless. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `unix` style (`lf`) then it will work as you have it configured above. You can try it on [online demo](http://eslint.org/demo/).

If you use `windows` styles (`crlf`), then you need to configure the rule like this:

```
{
    "eol-last": [2, "windows"]
}
```